# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: docker, debian

I can't build any container as simply user.
I think that exhausted all kwnos trought me possibilities, to solve this problem. Of corse I have tried add itself to group user using command

`groupadd docker`

`usermod -aG docker (user)`

after this I restart `docker` using command

`systemctl restart docker`

And If I switch to my user I still don't can build any container because i get error

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

after command
`docker status` i get below log

```
docker status
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since wto 2016-12-06 15:41:31 CET; 1min 35s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 26253 (dockerd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─26253 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
           └─26259 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --shim docker-containerd-shim --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/...

gru 06 15:41:30 myHost dockerd[26253]: time="2016-12-06T15:41:30.435228099+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs period"
gru 06 15:41:30 myHost dockerd[26253]: time="2016-12-06T15:41:30.435251931+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs quotas"
gru 06 15:41:30 myHost dockerd[26253]: time="2016-12-06T15:41:30.435393945+01:00" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
gru 06 15:41:30 myHost dockerd[26253]: time="2016-12-06T15:41:30.435753874+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
gru 06 15:41:30 myHost dockerd[26253]: .....time="2016-12-06T15:41:30.497465970+01:00" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
gru 06 15:41:30 myHost dockerd[26253]: time="2016-12-06T15:41:30.990080575+01:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemo...d IP address"
gru 06 15:41:31 myHost dockerd[26253]: time="2016-12-06T15:41:31.370184647+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
gru 06 15:41:31 myHost dockerd[26253]: time="2016-12-06T15:41:31.370332497+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
gru 06 15:41:31 myHost dockerd[26253]: time="2016-12-06T15:41:31.370401452+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=6b644ec graphdriver=aufs version=1.12.3
gru 06 15:41:31 myHost dockerd[26253]: time="2016-12-06T15:41:31.383585031+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
```

May be above warnings is important, and this is a tip to solve my problem ?

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised you had to add the docker group as that's not normal. Can you check who the owner of /var/run/docker.sock is? Also what OS is this on?

Comment: Maybe you just need to refresh your user, if you are logged in with ssh, exit and re-ssh. Else reboot your computer.
Sure it looks like the worst advice ever, but it happened to me a bunch of times ^^

Comment: I don't know how but I reboot PC, and execute again all command above and works... sometimes I to much belive in that linux don't need to restart